# why icon is not display as mention in document?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

As mention in document 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#tabs-icon-text
that tab will display icon.I used same code .but my icon is not display why ?
I used like that

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1" tabIcon="leaf" style='background-color:red!important'></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2" tabIcon="water"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

why leaf and water icon not display ?
http://plnkr.co/edit/XZf6ReT1YESQNgONgcMm?p=preview

Comment: Seems like icons are not loaded. I tried adding an `<ion-icon>` to your page1, but it doesn't show. How did you setup your Ionic 2 project? Can you show your local folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working in your plunker because you haven't loaded the css definitions but it would work in a real ionic project.

If you add

`<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">`

to your `index.html` file, it will work in the plunker